# strtok() reading the spaces at the end of string and not returning NULL

Tags: c, delimiter, strtok

I am using `fgets()` to read a line which contains integers values separated by spaces as follows:

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL)
```

After reading string in str, I am using `strtok()` to convert string in to tokens and then using `atoi()` function to convert these values in to integers.

```
token = strtok(str, s);
while( token != NULL)    //If token is NULL then don't convert it to integer
int d = atoi(token);
```

The output of the first input is as expected.

**Input-1:**

```
5 1 0 3 4\n
```

**Output-1:**

```
d=5
d=1
d=0
d=3
d=4
```

Now the problem occurs when I give a space after string and hit enter.

**Input-2:**

```
5 1 0 3 4 \n
```

**Output-2:**

```
d=5
d=1
d=0
d=3
d=4
d=0
```

So now my questions are:

**1.** Will `strtok()` not return NULL when there are only spaces at the end?

**2.** How to differentiate between the two zeros that are coming in output?

**3.** How can I avoid `strtok()` to read that final space or any number of spaces at the end?

Comment: You missed to tell us the actual parameters to strtok. Try this one: `strtok(str, " \n");`

Comment: `fgets` will keep the newline at the end. Consider including the newline (and maybe the tab for good measure) in your delimiter string: `strtok(str, " \n\t")`.

Comment: What is `s` ? `s` should be delimiter

Comment: @harper Thanks. It worked as I used `token = strtok(NULL, " \n");` i.e. space and newline together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are using is not correct.Delimiter passed as a 2nd parameter should be correct.

```
token = strtok(str," \n\t");  //should use delimiter
while( token != NULL) 
{
   int d = atoi(token);
   printf("%d\n",d);
   token = strtok(NULL," \n\t");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shan. I was confused in the delimiter part only so didn't pasted whole code. But now I used `token = strtok(NULL, " \n");`and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with the delimiter(s). *One* solution for *all* your questions is :

Please add space [ ] and newline [`\n`] both to your delimiter string, and optionally `\t`.

As per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) of `strtok()`

> *char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);*
>
> The *delim* argument specifies a set of bytes that delimit the tokens in the parsed string.

and

> A sequence of two or more contiguous delimiter bytes in the parsed string is considered to be a single delimiter.

So, you can use

```
char *s = " \n\t"
```

and then

```
token = strtok(str, s);
```

Comment: The strtok() function parses a string into a sequence of tokens. On the first call to [strtok()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) the string to be parsed should be specified in str. In each subsequent call that should parse the same string, **str should be NULL**. Why it should be NULL in subsequent calls?

Comment: @DeepakUniyal it should be NULL only if you want to parse the _same_ string again. For exaple, suppose you want to parse "My name is Sourav" based on delimiter space ` `. So here, you need to pass the string containing the line and the delimiter in first call to strtok, it will return "My", now if you want to get "name", you need to parse the same string again, in that case, you have to pass NULL as the first argument to _keep on_ parsing the same string. Hope this is clear now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Signature of the strtok is char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

delimiter can be space [ ], newline \n , coma [,] , tab [\t] anything that separate the two values in your string in a constant significant fashion are considered as delimiter.
Delimiter characters  at  the  start  or  end  of the string are ignored by strtok.

You can use n no of delimiter. as per your string you can use two delimiter 
1. space [ ]
2. \n

change:

1.token = strtok(str, " \n");
2.token = strtok(NULL," \n");